# How to figure out if I'm on the right path

Tags: unity, c++, career

I'm a software developer from Israel, I've been programming professionally since 2011, my first job was in HP software and lasted 2 years after which I decided that I want to pursue my dream in working in game development and focusing on C++.
for a year an a half I worked for a mobile kids games company, doing small mobile games for kids using C++ and Cocos2d-x.
Unfortunately I was laid off last December and since then I've been focusing my free time on studying Unreal engine 4, studying openGL and computer graphics and working on my C++ skills while searching for a new job.

I'm very passionate about computer & console games and especially the rendering part and my dream job would be to work on AAA games and to be a graphics programming specialist.
The problem is that there aren't any AAA game companies in Israel so I started looking at positions in Europe and also in other jobs that involves computer graphics but aren't necessarily in games.

Last week I got a job offer for a small start up making a game in the "Clash of Clans" genre, the company seems nice, its not my type of games but I'm sure it presents all kinds of challenge but my biggest concern is the fact that the game is implemented in Unity and Python, which are two technologies I'm not so crazy about.

I wonder if I should take the job or keep looking for something that involves more C++,OpenGL,DirectX etc.
Do you think that taking a Unity\Python job will take me too far from the OpenGL\DirectX goal I'm trying to reach?

I know that good software developers aren't supposed to limit themselves to a certain programming language but I think its good to become really professional at something specific instead of changing language every 2 years.
I guess its being a specialist vs. a generalist question.

What do you guys think? should I take this job even though I have some concerns? should I keep searching? maybe doing some freelance work in the meantime?

any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My take on this is that if you can find a job closer to where you want to be than where you currently are, you should take it.  Since you currently are not employed and this offer is for a game development position I'd say go for it.  Being employed as a game programmer, even if its for the "wrong technologies" makes you a lot more hireable by the places you would like to work for, versus a hobbyist game Dev who has no job.  If you take this job, keep honing the skills you want to grow (in your spare time if needed) and feel free to keep searching for other jobs and if a better one comes along, take your step up.  Of course, try your best to be respectful to the folks who have given you a chance at their company and don't leave at a critical time if you can help it.   I'm a self taught game programmer who is technically a high school drop out, but am now an engine programmer at Blizzard working on StarCraft 2 and heroes of the storm.  Took about 14 years of hard work, and I had to start off in business software, but using the above advice I crawled my way up to a respectable position (:  most importantly though, learn everything you can about everything you can.  You need to improve your skills constantly to be able to take those steps up.  It sounds like you are on the right track though if you keel it up!

Comment: thanks for the advice. what I forgot to mention that I'm 30. having to go to the army for 3 years in Israel and then studying for a degree for 4 years instead of 3 kinda puts me behind with the rest of the world

Comment: It's a cliche I know, but age is just a number.  You may get there late, but when you do get there, you'll have different experiences to bring to the table.  Think about how many games are based on war and military (either strategy or first person shooters etc), and think about how few game developers actually have military experience.  You'll be ahead of the curve there and have some interesting perspectives to bring to the table.  Keep at it, you'll get there (:

Comment: Thanks, I guess that if I do graphics stuff on unity and keep on studying directx and openGL on the side I would be able to get into graphic programming positions right?